# Reflector generated Lambda Expression, how to get back back actual Linq Query?

Tags: linq, reflection, lambda, reflector

I'm using Reflector to decompile some binaries. I'm having problem with Lambda Expressions and [methodof](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/Default.aspx?blog=entry.9b4d67c1109f490186dbc6353975329d) which doesn't compile. lambda Expression seems super complicated to me and I have no idea how to convert it back to Compilable LINQ Code. here is the code:

```
public double? LoadSumRialAmount(long functionId, long? subFunctionId)
{
        ParameterExpression expression;
        if (!subFunctionId.HasValue)
        {
            return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
                where func.FunctionId == functionId
                select func).Select<SubFunctionEntity, double?>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<SubFunctionEntity, double?>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Multiply(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(SubFunctionEntity), "func"), (MethodInfo) methodof(SubFunctionEntity.get_Volume)), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(expression, (MethodInfo) methodof(SubFunctionEntity.get_RialAmount))), new ParameterExpression[] { expression })).Sum();
        }
        return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
            where (func.FunctionId == functionId) && (func.SubFunctionId != subFunctionId)
            select func).Select<SubFunctionEntity, double?>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<SubFunctionEntity, double?>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Multiply(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(SubFunctionEntity), "func"), (MethodInfo) methodof(SubFunctionEntity.get_Volume)), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(expression, (MethodInfo) methodof(SubFunctionEntity.get_RialAmount))), new ParameterExpression[] { expression })).Sum();
}
```

p.s another error is SubFunctionEntity class has a "Volume" property, and I don't understand why this code is calling some kind of static property on it like: SubFunctionEntity.get_Volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)? It even has some options to control if you want to produce LINQ "function" syntax or `from... where` syntax (`View->Options->Decompiler->Decompile query expression` and `Decompile anonymous methods/lambdas`)

For your other question: `SubFunctionEntity.get_Volume` is the getter of the property `Volume` of the class `SubFunctionEntity`.

`(MethodInfo) methodof(SubFunctionEntity.get_Volume)` is the same as `typeof(SubFunctionEntity).GetProperty("Volume").GetGetMethod()`, only done at compile time instead that at runtime. The problem is that C# doesn't have a `methodof` "function".

If you really want to use what the Reflector gave you, this is the "corrected" version:

```
public double? LoadSumRialAmount(long functionId, long? subFunctionId)
{
    ParameterExpression expression;
    if (!subFunctionId.HasValue)
    {
        return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
                where func.FunctionId == functionId
                select func).Select<SubFunctionEntity, double?>(Expression.Lambda<Func<SubFunctionEntity, double?>>(Expression.Multiply(Expression.Property(expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SubFunctionEntity), "func"), typeof(SubFunctionEntity).GetProperty("Volume").GetGetMethod()), Expression.Property(expression, typeof(SubFunctionEntity).GetProperty("RialAmount").GetGetMethod())), new ParameterExpression[] { expression })).Sum();
    }
    return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
            where (func.FunctionId == functionId) && (func.SubFunctionId != subFunctionId)
            select func).Select<SubFunctionEntity, double?>(Expression.Lambda<Func<SubFunctionEntity, double?>>(Expression.Multiply(Expression.Property(expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SubFunctionEntity), "func"), typeof(SubFunctionEntity).GetProperty("Volume").GetGetMethod()), Expression.Property(expression, typeof(SubFunctionEntity).GetProperty("RialAmount").GetGetMethod())), new ParameterExpression[] { expression })).Sum();
}
```

Note that you'll need some using:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Ah... the most complex expression is : `func => (func.Volume * func.RialAmount)` so you could write the method as:

```
public double? LoadSumRialAmount(long functionId, long? subFunctionId)
{
    if (!subFunctionId.HasValue)
    {
        return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
                where func.FunctionId == functionId
                select func).Select(func => (func.Volume * func.RialAmount)).Sum();
    }
    return (from func in base.MetaData.SubFunction
            where (func.FunctionId == functionId) && (func.SubFunctionId != subFunctionId)
            select func).Select(func => (func.Volume * func.RialAmount)).Sum();
}
```

Addendum: checked, the ILSpy produce random garbage similar-but different to Reflector

Comment: @mani_007 the `into func` creates an `IEnumerable<FunctionEnctity>`. The `where` is probably wrong because it's trying to compare an `IEnumerable` with `sectionEntity.SectionId`. Try changing it to `into func from func2 in func where fun2.SectionId == sectionEntity.SectionId ...` but remember that now you have `func2` that is the element of `func`